# Is it somehow possible to convert a literal linebreak (and other literal characters) to a PHP_EOL, etc.?

Tags: php

I'm in a situation where I've done this:

```
$special_constants =
[
    'truthful'          => true,
    'falsey'            => false,
    'LINEBREAK'         => PHP_EOL
];
```

I then define() each of those keys to their values, so that I can use this in my application code:

```
$a_bool = truthful;
echo 'Yo!' . LINEBREAK;
```

etc... So far, so good.

Now, in a special context, I'm trying to output literally "true" and "PHP_EOL":

```
echo $special_constants['truthful']; // Does not output "true".
echo $special_constants['LINEBREAK']; // Does not output "PHP_EOL".
```

I've also tried:

```
echo (string)$special_constants['truthful']; // Does not output "true".
echo (string)$special_constants['LINEBREAK']; // Does not output "PHP_EOL".
```

Is there some way to output the literal strings "true" and "PHP_EOL" from my array of constants? That is, ***without*** making a duplicate array with all the values in quotes, which would be a solution but a very inelegant one, which I'm trying to avoid.

I'm guessing that there might be some neat hidden PHP function called something cryptic which does this for me.

Comment: If you're doing it in a special context as you say, why not just output it with `echo PHP_EOL` directly for this one use case?

Comment: It has to be dynamic. It's transforming existing code.